# having trouble in changing the label color of subplot according to the scatter matrix

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

```
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array

iris = datasets.load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
colors = array(50*['r']+50*['g']+50*['b'])
_ = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, c=colors, figsize=[8,8], s=100, alpha=0.8)
plt.figure()

plt.imshow(X = [np.unique(iris.target)])
_ = plt.xticks(ticks=np.unique(iris.target),labels=iris.target_names)
```

[image]

I tried to add cmap parameter to the plt.imshow() but this parameter is ignored if X is RGB(A) this is what written in documentation [Hyperlink](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). I tried putting `X = colors` instead but it is not working.

Comment: Additionally no my answer, I'd like to leave a note. Are you sure the "c=colors" is doing what you expect? (i.e. colouring correctly according to the names)

Answer (score 0):

We can import colors:

```
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
```

And then use our discrete set of three colors in imshow:

```
plt.imshow(X = [np.unique(iris.target)], cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(["r", "g", "b"]) )
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ListedColormap' this is the error I am getting when I add these lines. Have to checked whether it is working?

Comment: That's because we were using "colors" for two different things. I updated my answer calling matplotlib.colors as mcolors.